# Replacing space in text from a web-page

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I have two lines of text which have long space (more like 14-15 spaces) before the actual text. I have tried simple replace to split and merge but nothing is working. I have also tried trim and the worst thing is that ASCII gives code of 32. But nothing works. Here is the text :

```
                                                              your heartburn symptoms
                    Certain foods, such as fat, chocolate, caffeine and alcohol can aggravate heartburn symptoms 1
                    Certain foods
```

(BTW it's not like it looks it is. In my actual richtextbox, when I select the space it gets selected as one big piece of space like a tab and i have also tried replacing vbtab but no use)

What I want is :

```
your heartburn symptoms
Certain foods, such as fat, chocolate, caffeine and alcohol can aggravate heartburn symptoms 1
Certain foods
```

Believe me I have tried almost 7-8 diffferent function but now I am going mad. Some of my logic :

```
Dim lineArray As String() = rtfArticle.Lines

        For z As Integer = 0 To lineArray.Length - 1
            Dim w As String() = lineArray(z).Split(" ")
            MsgBox(lineArray(z))
            Dim tmp As String = ""

            For Each s34 As String In w
                If (s34 <> " ") Then
                    temp = temp & " " & s34
                End If
            Next
            lineArray(z) = temp
        Next
```

It completely messes up the code. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Dim lineArray As String() = rtfArticle.Lines
For z As Integer = 0 To lineArray.Length - 1
    lineArray(z) = lineArray(z).Trim()
Next
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for `Trim()` says:

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the
>   current String object.

Comment: lolollolol. how the hell did this work? I feel like such a noob. I mean i had tried trim with individual lines but it didn't work. Is there something in this which iam missing? And yeah thanks a ton xD